# Firefox Recent Bookmarks Not Collapsing in the Bookmarks List in Ubuntu

Tags: firefox

I have Ubuntu 16.04 & Firefox 49.

When I use Firefox 49 in Windows 7 I can right click on the *Recently Bookmarked* heading in the bookmarks list & get the list that appears under the heading to collapse.

When I try this in Firefox 49 when using Ubuntu nothing happens because I'm not presented with panel of options. When I right click on the heading nothing happens.

How can I collapse the Recently Bookmarked list from the Bookmarks panel?

Comment: Do you mean in the bookmarks sidepane (Ctrl + B)? I dont see any difference in behavior between win7 and Ubuntu 16.04 on Firefox 49.

Comment: @Bruni: not the side panel, but the pop down panel when the Bookmarks tab is clicked.